# divisibility: number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The equation is $$(4x^2 - y^2)^l + (4ay)^m = (4{x}^2 + {y}^2)^n.$$

Here I have taken $l= 2l'$ and $ n = 2n'$. Substituting $l$ and $n$ in above equation, we have
$$(4 a y)^m = ((4{x}^2 + {y}^2)^{n'} + (4{x}^2 - {y}^2)^{l'})((4{x}^2 + {y}^2)^{n'} - (4{x}^2 - {y}^2)^{l'}).$$
Here we are taking $$A = (4{x}^2 + {y}^2)^{n'} + (4{x}^2 - {y}^2)^{l'}$$ and $$ B = (4{x}^2 + {y}^2)^{n'} - (4{x}^2 - {y}^2)^{l'}.$$ Here $l$, $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $x$ is *odd* and $y$ is *odd prime*.

My question is what is $\gcd (A , B)$ ?

Comment: Least common factor of $(A,B)$ is clearly $2$ as $A$ and $B$ are clearly even...

Comment: @A-M I know that....$gcd$ asks for the highest common factor...giving the least common factor may provide an idea....